# Geojson not rendered with Mapnik

Tags: geojson, mapnik, tilemill, rendering

I am trying to generate a tile with Mapnik with a GeoJSON. The stylesheet.xml with the part to render the GeoJSON is the following:

```
<Style name="cities" filter-mode="first">
  <Rule>
    <MarkersSymbolizer width="50" fill="#ff4455" stroke="#881133" allow-overlap="true" ignore-placement="true" />
  </Rule>
</Style>
<Layer name="cities"
  srs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs">
    <StyleName>cities</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
       <Parameter name="file"><![CDATA[/home/uli/projects/tiles/test.geojson]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="layer"><![CDATA[OGRGeoJSON]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="type"><![CDATA[ogr]]></Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
```

It does not render the GeoJSON. Also it doesn't throw an error. If I use a shapefile with the same settings (except type and file) it works fine. Any ideas why it is not rendered?

I used TileMill to generate the XML. The GeoJSON is shown properly in TileMill.

The GeoJSON file I used is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a140b557716c4237e96.

Comment: There is not enough data to answer the question. What is in the GeoJSON file? Is the path correct? If you create your project in TileMill, did you try to `carto -l project.mml > test.xml` and then feed it to Mapnik? Can it be a projection error?

Comment: @IljaZverev, sorry for the late response. I added to the question a sample GeoJSON file. The path is correct. I tried `carto -l project.mml > test.xml`, it produces the same xml and also there the GeoJSON won't show up.

Answer (score 2):

Things may be different from when you posted this originally.  With current Mapnik versions (3.0.10 for example), this should work:

```
<Style name="cities" filter-mode="first">
  <Rule>
    <MarkersSymbolizer width="50" fill="#ff4455" stroke="#881133" allow-overlap="true" ignore-placement="true" />
  </Rule>
</Style>
<Layer name="cities"
  srs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs">
    <StyleName>cities</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
       <Parameter name="file">/home/uli/projects/tiles/test.geojson</Parameter>
       <Parameter name="type">geojson</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
</Layer>
```

Basically, the plugin is now called "geojson", and accepts at most 3 parameters: "file" (required), "type" (required), and "encoding" (defaults to "utf-8").